# How to extract numbers within a specified range from a column?

Tags: sql

I have a column in my schema which contains values as follows:

```
male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 1.63

male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 1.85

male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 1.75
```

i want to make a query that extracts all the objects which has numbers lies between 1.63 and 1.75, Note that the numbers specified above are embedded in a string as you see the 3 examples above, and note also that these whole string is stored in one column, any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in many SQL dialects as:

```
select *
from t
where right(col, 4) between '1.63' and '1.75'
```

The string comparison works because the numbers have the decimal place in the same position.

Comment: excuse me, what is the meaning of where right(col, 3) between '1.63' and '1.75' ?

Comment: In many databases, `right()` is a string function that takes characters at the end of the string.  `between` is a comparison operator that works on all data type.  So, this is taking the last four digits (I miscounted the first time) and comparing them to the strings.

Comment: is there's other method that make the same function as right() but from any place in the string not restricted only to the end of the string?

Comment: @JavaPlayer . . . That function would be `substr()` or `substring()` in most databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableName 
where convert(int, substr(columnName,LENGTH(columnName)-4,4)) BETWEEN 1.75 AND 1.63
```

This should work without limiting the Integer part to some syntax ((d.dd) for example) but requires it to be of length 4.

**Edit**

Between has more elegant usage.

Answer (score 0):

While the solutions provide  work with the small sample set provided they may not work with all possible data in the column. If for instances you have data such as the data below

```
male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 1.63
male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 1.85
male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 1.75
male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 11.63
male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 11.85
male, Brown, Blue, Small body build, 11.75
```

then extracting data using the right(col,4) solution would also return those rows with a value of 11.64 and 11.75 as the right(col,4) wile ignore the 1 representing the 10's.

The right(col,4) solution also ignores the overhead of possible string to int conversion and also assumes that right(col,4) is always an int.

A better solution would be to find the last ',' in the column and then take the substring of that and compare to required range.

An even better solution and one that would be much more efficient would be to break the data into separate columns such as Sex, HairColour, EyeColour, Build, Height etc.
This would allow far better database performance, allow for better data extraction/querying etc